# Getting away from BackgroundWorker towards TPL for a logging class

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker

I currently have written a simple event logger in the view of the old `Backgroundworker` class. I am trying to convert it to a TPL implementation.

I do not have enough usage with threading in C# to really prefer one over the other but I do know that TPL is becoming more preferred to I wanted to stick with it as much as I can. Another reason is that with the current code I can not find an easy way to make the `EventLog` class thread safe. I am finding myself using `BeginInvoke` to write to the log from non UI threads which just seems messy to me.

So here is the original code.

```
public class EventLog
{
    public String LogPath { get; set; }
    public List<LogEvent> Events { get; private set; }

    public static EventLog Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<EventLog> lazyInstance = new Lazy<EventLog>(() => new EventLog());

    private EventLog()
    {
        Events = new List<LogEvent>();
        LogPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        LogPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(LogPath);
        LogPath = LogPath.Replace("file:\\", "");
        LogPath = LogPath + "\\Log.txt";
    }

    public override void publish(LogEvent newEvent)
    {
        Events.Add(newEvent);
        if (!LogEventWriter.Instance.IsBusy)
            LogEventWriter.Instance.RunWorkerAsync(LogPath);
        LogEventWriter.Instance.LogEvents.Add(newEvent);
    }
}

internal class LogEventWriter : BackgroundWorker
{
    public BlockingCollection<LogEvent> LogEvents { get; set; }

    public static LogEventWriter Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<LogEventWriter> lazyInstance = new Lazy<LogEventWriter>(() => new LogEventWriter());

    private LogEventWriter()
    {
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        LogEvents = new BlockingCollection<LogEvent>();
    }

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument != null && e.Argument is String)
        {
            String logPath = (String)e.Argument;
            using (StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
            {
                while (!CancellationPending)
                {
                    LogEvent anEvent = LogEvents.Take();
                    logFile.WriteLine(anEvent.Message);
                    logFile.Flush();
                    if (anEvent.Message.Contains("Application Terminated"))
                        break;
                }
                logFile.Close();
            }
        }
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

My current train of thought for the log is to write the log to a file ASAP in case of a system failure so that the log will have as much information as it can. This is what the `Backgroundworker` is for. I also just keep a `List<LogEvent>` in the `EventLog` class so that the user might be able to search the current log for specific events (not fully implemented/polished off).

Here is my current TPL solution. I have tried as best I can to wrap the logging functionality into `Task`s but it I still feel like I should have a function akin to `publish` and not have to directly place `LogEvent`s into a `BlockingCollection<>` so that I can run the logging on a separate thread from the main UI.

Also is there a cleaner way to stop the `Task`s without having to send a "special" `LogEvent` to them to `break` from their loops?

```
public class EventLog
{
    public static EventLog Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<EventLog> lazyInstance = new Lazy<EventLog>(() => new EventLog());

    public String LogPath { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentQueue<LogEvent> Events { get; set; }

    private EventLog()
    {
        Events = new ConcurrentQueue<LogEvent>();
        WriteQueue = new BlockingCollection<LogEvent>();
        LogEventQueue = new BlockingCollection<LogEvent>();

        LogPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        LogPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(LogPath);
        LogPath = LogPath.Replace("file:\\", "");
        LogPath = LogPath + "\\LogASDF.txt";

        StartManager();
        StartWriter();
    }

    public BlockingCollection<LogEvent> LogEventQueue { get; set; }
    private void StartManager()
    {
        var writeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                LogEvent anEvent = LogEventQueue.Take();
                Events.Enqueue(anEvent);
                WriteQueue.Add(anEvent);
                if (anEvent.Message.Contains("Application Terminated"))
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    private BlockingCollection<LogEvent> WriteQueue { get; set; }
    private void StartWriter()
    {
        var writeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(LogPath, true))
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    LogEvent anEvent = WriteQueue.Take();
                    logFile.WriteLine(anEvent.Message);
                    logFile.Flush();
                    if (anEvent.Message.Contains("Application Terminated"))
                        break;
                }
                logFile.Close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

1. How can I properly use `CancellationToken` to cancel both of the tasks? I do not see how if `BlockingCollection` is blocking, I always have to "pulse" the collection to get it to unblock.
2. Is there a "cleaner" way to insert an `LogEvent` into the log without having to directly insert it into `LogEventQueue`?

Comment: `LogEvent` and `EventLog` is bad naming for me...

Comment: Yeah I know.. I haven't exactly polished this code up just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your code isn't `thread-safe` as you have this:

```
public List<LogEvent> Events { get; private set; }
```

`List<T>` isn't thread safe, and can be changed from outer code. And I can't see is it used at all.

Also, you really should use `CancellationToken` in your code because of in other case you can get troubles: for example, you have 5 messages in queue, and you decide to cancel your work. In this case check for `Shutdown Log` will break loop only after some time, which is confusing for end-user of your class.

Also, there is an overload for [`BlockingCollection<T>.Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381908.aspx) Method with `CancellationToken`, but in case of cancel you'll get to catch the `OperationCanceledException`:

```
try
{
    LogEvent anEvent = WriteQueue.Take(CancellationPending);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    // handle stop here;
}
```

Infinite loop in very bad practice in multi-threading, I suggest not to use it.

Comment: Yes, I was about to post an edit where I used another `ConcurrentCollection` for `Events`. // I guess that was specifically my question. How can I use a `CacellationToken` when `BlockingCollection` is blocking? I always have to "pulse" the `BlockingCollection` to get it to stop blocking so that I can check a token even.

Comment: Ahh I did not see that argument for `Take` not sure how I missed it. In my original post I had a second question, would you care to address it? // Also, could you suggest a way to not use the `while(true)` to continually wait/write to the log?

Comment: I see how to fix it. When I use the `CancellationToken`s I can use them for the loop instead of `true`.

Comment: Are there any questions left in your post?

Comment: No you helped me through everything for this question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would handle this using .net 4.5. All access to the event queue is synchronous, so no locking or syncing needed:

```
public class EventLog
{
    public String LogPath { get; set; }
    public List<LogEvent> Events {get;set;}
    private isProcessing = false;
    public CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private CancellationToken _token;

    public static EventLog Instance { get { return lazyInstance.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<EventLog> lazyInstance = new Lazy<EventLog>(() => new EventLog());

    private EventLog()
    {
        Events = new List<LogEvent>();
        Events.CollectionChanged += Events_CollectionChanged;
        LogPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        LogPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(LogPath);
        LogPath = LogPath.Replace("file:\\", "");
        LogPath = LogPath + "\\Log.txt";
        _token = cts.Token; 
    }

    public override void publish(LogEvent newEvent)
    {
        Events.Add(newEvent);
        if (!isProcessing)
            ProcessLog();
    }

    private async void ProcessLog()
    {
        while (Events.Count > 0)
        {
            isProcessing = true;
            LogEvent e = EventLogs.First();
            await Task.Run (() => { WriteLog(e,token); },_token);
            EventLogs.Remove(e);
            if (_token.IsCancellationRequested == true)
                EventLogs.Clear();
        }
        isProcessing = false;
    }

    private void WriteLog(LogEvent e,CancellationToken token)
    {
        using (StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(LogPath, true))
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                logFile.WriteLine(e.Message);
                logFile.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added cancellation token.
Edit 2: Added WriteLog function.